# Create groups based on column value with variable rolling window

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

Good morning,

I'm struggling in the section of a data.table operation.

### Reproductible Data

```
set.seed(5)
df <- data.table(
  id = c(paste0("id", seq(0,9))),
  booleean = c(TRUE, FALSE, rep(TRUE, 3), rep(FALSE,2), rep(TRUE,2),FALSE),
  value = rnorm(10, 14, 5))

     id booleean  value
 1: id0     TRUE    9.79
 2: id1    FALSE   20.92
 3: id2     TRUE    7.72
 4: id3     TRUE   14.35
 5: id4     TRUE   22.55
 6: id5    FALSE   10.98
 7: id6    FALSE   11.63
 8: id7     TRUE   10.82
 9: id8     TRUE   12.57
10: id9    FALSE   14.69
```

I'm trying to assign a new group value based on a booleean column value. In my code the `TRUE/FALSE` logic is based on timestamp comparison, the idea is to regroup close events together.

### Goal

The rolling window I'm looking to define is `[FALSE, all TRUE]`. The first individual of a group is always `FALSE` (except the first row of the datatable), then all other individuals of the group must be `TRUE`. When I encounter a new `FALSE`, we create a new group.

### Desired Output

```
     id booleean   value   new_group
 1: id0     TRUE    9.79         1
 2: id1    FALSE   20.92         2
 3: id2     TRUE    7.72         2
 4: id3     TRUE   14.35         2
 5: id4     TRUE   22.55         2
 6: id5    FALSE   10.98         3
 7: id6    FALSE   11.63         4
 8: id7     TRUE   10.82         4
 9: id8     TRUE   12.57         4
10: id9    FALSE   14.69         5
```

Comment: Would this work for you? `df$new_group <- cumsum(!df$booleean) + 1` (though this assumes first row is `TRUE`, which was not clear in the goal)...

Comment: Writing this question, I realize I could define a rolling window `[FALSE, FALSE]` and delete the last element. In the case `[FALSE, FALSE]` I only get `[FALSE]`, which is good. In the case `[FALSE, TRUE, FALSE]`, I get `[FALSE, TRUE]` which is also good.

Comment: @Ben Yes thank you it appears to be working ! Could you explain the logic behind a cumulative sum of boolean ? How does it create a variable rolling window ? I intuitevly understand it but I have trouble translating it algorithmically

Comment: in this case, a logical vector is coerced into numeric for `cumsum`...if you try `cumsum(c(T, F, T, F))` you get `1 1 2 2`...where each `TRUE` will increase the sum by 1...in the above example, `!df$booleean` will evaluate to `TRUE` (and increase by 1) when a `FALSE` is present...